# Do I have to flush the underlying OutputStream when wrapped and used as WritableByteChannel?

Tags: java, io, nio

Let's say I have a method whites some bytes to given channel.

```java
static void doWithChannel(final WritableByteChannel channel)
    throws IOException {

    // write some
}
```

Then any caller with an `OutputStream` can call like this, right?

```java
static void doWithStream(final OutputStream stream)
    throws IOException {

    doWithChannel(Channels.newChannel(stream));
    // stream.flush(); // is this really required?
    // should creator or broker invoke flush() on the stream?
}
```

My question is that should any entity(creator or broker) call the `flush()` on the stream?

Comment: Unspecified. It can't hurt. If the method does nothing it is instantaneous compared to the I/O.